# Perturbation of the boundary conditions in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

**Example:** Given the following PDE:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y^2} =0
$$
, subjected to the Dirichlet boundary conditions:
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
V(0,y)&=f_1(y)\\
V(m,y)&=f_2(y)\\
V(x,0)&=g_1(x)\\
V(x,n)&=g_2(x)
\end{align*}
\right.
$$

Let $V_1$ be the solution of the PDE above.

Let $V_2$ be a function that also satisfies the PDE and that:
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
V_2(0,y)&=f_1(y)+\epsilon_1(y)\\
V_2(m,y)&=f_2(y)+\epsilon_2(y)\\
V_2(x,0)&=g_1(x)+\delta_1(x)\\
V_2(x,n)&=g_2(x)+\delta_2(x)
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
where $\epsilon ,\delta \approx 0$.

**My question is:** Does $V_2$ "look" similar to $V_1$? By this I mean:
$$
V_2(x,y)-V_1(x,y) \approx 0 \text{ for any } x,y:0\leq x \leq m,0\leq y\leq n
$$
I would also appreciate if you can refer me to any theory that can answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: since $W=V_2-V_1$ is harmonic and satisfies the boundary conditions
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
W(0,y)&=\epsilon_1(y)\\
W(m,y)&=\epsilon_2(y)\\
W(x,0)&=\delta_1(x)\\
W(x,n)&=\delta_2(x)
\end{align*}
\right.,
$$
 by the [Maximum Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) it is bounded by the largest value of $\epsilon,\delta$ on the boundary.

Comment: Thank you. If the PDE is not the Laplace's equation, does the conclusion still apply?

Comment: That depends on the form of the equation. If you've got something that's uniformly elliptic, the [Hopf version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_maximum_principle) of the maximum principle applies.

Comment: I see. There are two other small related issues:

1. Does the conclusion apply to the 3D Laplace's equation?

2. Does the conclusion still apply when the boundary condition is an arbitrary set of (periodic) conditions?

Comment: In any number of dimensions, in any connected open set. And provided the difference in the boundary conditions is small and independent of the function, yes.

Comment: Thank you! Do the two links you provided contain enough information about the answer to my questions (both in the OP and in the comment section)? Otherwise, I'd appreciate if you could point me to a complete theory. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, the Wikipedia articles have references to some standard books on PDE, which should cover this in full detail.